# How to use pyplot.text() in a cycle to print different string on plot after each cycle

Tags: python-2.7, text, matplotlib

I've got a question on pyplot.text() when in a cycle. I'm printing a Truss so I need to assign different letters to each joint, but I can't find a way to do that using a cycle I've already created that stores the coordinates of each joint. Any ideas how to do it? Help will be appreciated.

I'm using the command in the following way:

```
pyplot.text(x_coordinate, y_coordinate, 'r$text', fontsize = 10)
```

So the real question would be how to change that $text each time for a given string, for example:

```
Words = ['A','B','C']
for i in Words:
    pyplot.text(x_coordinate,y_coordinate, i, fontsize=20)
```

This is what I *meant* to do in the first place. 
Just don't know how to do it the right way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest would surely be:

```
Words = ['A','B','C']
for i,word in enumerate(Words):
    pyplot.text(x_coordinate[i],y_coordinate[i], word, fontsize=20)
```

assuming `x_coordinate` and `y_coordinate` are sequences of the same length as `Words`.

Perhaps more natural would be to store your coordinates as a list of `(x,y)` tuples and (assuming you want labels `A`, `B`, etc. and there aren't more than 26 of them):

```
for i, (x,y) in enumerate(coords):
    # make text label: 'A', 'B', 'C', ...
    label = chr(i+65)
    pyplot.text(x, y, label, fontsize=20)
```

Comment: Well, I already have my coordinates in tuples in the real program, is just that even though I assigned the correct coordinates I wasn't able to print different words for each different coordinate.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Now I've got an error 'only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars' that is associated with the label = chr(i+65) 
What do I do? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hmm... are you sure you have the `for` loop correct? `i` is the counter produced  by `enumerate` and should be an integer. What do you get if you `print i` inside the loop?

Comment: I'm sorry, it was my mistake. The i was not a number but a tuple in my for, that's why I got the error. Now I got it!! Thanks for the help!